# Removing readonly from root

Tags: permissions, root, steam, 19.10

how can I remove read only from my root drive?
I have ubuntu 19.10
I want to install CS go in ubuntu but my home drive has not much capacity
I want to install it into my root drive but i cant due to readonly setting.

Comment: just create a dir as root then change ownership to your normal user ... `sudo mkdir /some/dir`  then issue  `sudo chown myname:myname /some/dir`   edit myname with your actual login name

Comment: Do i have to make this directory in root drive or can i make it in my other partition?

Comment: open up a terminal ( control + alt + t) and issue `df -m`  now look for the column `Mounted on` with the value '/'  ... this row is important ... its your root partition and every dir on it will share is available space which is show on column `Use%`   of that row ... on output of `df -m` if you have multiple partitions with enough Available space yes you can use another partition just avoid once with `Filesystem` values of udev, tmpfs, /dev/loop* as they are for system use only